# Execute a command using a Linux Mint shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I'm looking to add a shortcut to Linux Mint (`Menu` → `Control Center` → `Keyboard Shortcuts`) to execute `xkill` when I press <kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. I've encountered two problems:

1) <kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd> toggles the `Menu` in Linux Mint, which it looks like is preventing the shortcut from working. (<kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd> shows up in the `shortcut field` as `Mod4` on my computer.) I want <kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd> to continue to toggle the `Menu` unless it's used in conjunction with the <kbd>X</kbd> key.

2) Even if another shortcut is used (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example), `xkill` is not triggered when `/usr/bin/xkill` is set for the `name`.

I'm using Linux Mint 16 Petra – Mate Edition.